# Casting to chromecast, no sound

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-conversion, chromecast

When I cast a movie to Chromecast, I get no sound.

So I decided to convert the original video from `eac3` audio encoding to `mp3`.

```
ffmpeg -i media-original.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec mp3 media-mp3.mkv
```

But now Chromecast (I'm using Chrome to do Chromecast via SMPlayer) fails to play the media completely and says

```
chromecast.smplayer.info.says
Playback failed
```

So it went from not being able to play the sound to completely failing to play the media.

So I did a comparison of the two media files

```
 ffprobe media-original.mkv 2>&1 > /dev/null
 ffprobe media-mp3.mkv 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

Left side no audio, right side can't play the file at all:

[image: Left side no audio, right side can't play the file at all]

So the main difference that I can see, is that the original has `eac3` ([which cannot be used by Chromecast](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media#audio_codecs)) which explains why audio is mute. But the right one - which fails to play completely - has `stereo` instead of `6 channels` and has `ENCODER: Lavc58.54.100 libmp3lame`.

What does that mean, and how do I used FFmpeg to correctly change audio from `eac3` to `mp3` without switching to `stereo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matroska (`.mkv`) isn't listed as one of the supported media container formats in [Supported Media for Google Cast](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media).

Since your video is H.264 you can use MP4. You'll only have to re-encode the audio because eac3 isn't listed as a supported audio format:

```
ffmpeg -i media-original.mkv -c:v copy -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

If it does not like the 5.1 audio channel layout then downmix to stereo:

```
ffmpeg -i media-original.mkv -c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 2 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

To help you choose the appropriate media type string you can use `ffprobe`. Example:

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=codec_type,codec_name,profile,level video.mp4
[STREAM]
codec_name=h264
profile=High
codec_type=video
level=30
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
codec_name=aac
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
[/STREAM]
```

`level 30` means level 3.0.

Comment: what's the reason for `-movflags +faststart`

Comment: @JeniaIvanov `-movflags +faststart` relocates some info after encoding is finished. It moves the info from the end of the file to the beginning of the file. The info can only be made once encoding is finished, so that is why it isn't made immediately at the start. This info is required for playback, so this option is useful if viewers will watch via progressive download. Otherwise they would have to download the video completely before it can start playing. It is only useful for MP4/M4A/M4V/MOV.

Comment: So it looks to me that when I use `eac3` with 6 channels (5.1 audio) then there's no sound. When I convert it to `aac` with 6 channels, the movie won't start playing it all. It needs to be `aac` with stereo.

Comment: I have **one final question**: how do I only convert the audio and keep the `mkv` final format?

Comment: Maybe video with surround sound have no audio because my tv has only two speakers? lol :)

Comment: @JeniaIvanov For Matroska output just change `output.mp4` to `output.mkv`. You can also remove `-movflags +faststart` because mkv will ignore that. Your two speakers should still play the FL and FR channels from the 5.1 audio, but it is also possible that 5.1 AAC is not supported by Cast, your player, browser, decoder, etc.

Comment: I figured it out. My chrome dongle can only play vorbis or aac stereo. Have no idea why...

Comment: On my Ubuntu 20, Chrome 81 wouldn't play the audio, before casting even. Converting to AAC in MKV didn't solve that problem, but to MP did: `-c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 2 -movflags +faststart output.mp4`.